# python regex statements on a single line

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex but I wanted to make them into a single expression without affecting the output.The code below saves a list of words from a text and saves to a list.

```
import re
a=[]
with open('qwert.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        res = re.findall(r'(?:Prof[.](\w+))', line)
        if res: 
            a.extend(res)
        res = re.findall(r'(?:As (\w+))', line)
        if res:
            a.extend(res)
        res = re.findall(r'\w+(?==\w)', line)
        if res:
            a.extend(res)

print a
```

qwert.txt

```
As every
prof.John and Prof.Keel and goodthing=him
Prof.Tensa
Keel a good person As kim
kim is fine
Prof.Jees
As John winning Nobel prize
As Mary wins all prize
sa for ask
car

he=is good
```

output:

```
['every', 'Keel', 'goodthing', 'Tensa', 'kim', 'Jees', 'John', 'Mary', 'he']
```

How can make the three regex stmts onto a single line?

Comment: could you post the contents of `qwert.txt` file?

Comment: @AvinashRaj posted incl. output!

Comment: Extra note, the `if res` is unnecessary here, extending by an empty list does what you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the operator "|", it allows you to find one or the other expression.
 `res = re.findall(r'(?:Prof[.](\w+))|(?:As (\w+))|(?:\w+(?==\w))', line)`

Comment: it doesnot print anything

Comment: `>>> re.findall(regexp, 'Prof.ddfsdf As sdfsdf')`                                 
`[('ddfsdf', ''), ('', 'sdfsdf')]`

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose the last `\w+` inside capturing group and also you need to enable multiline modifier.

```
>>> import re
>>> a=[]
>>> with open('qwert.txt', 'r') as f:
...     for line in f:
...         res = re.findall(r'(?:Prof[.](\w+))|(?:As (\w+))|(\w+)(?==\w)', line, re.M)
...         if res:
...             a.extend(res)
... 
>>> a
[('', 'every', ''), ('Keel', '', ''), ('', '', 'goodthing'), ('Tensa', '', ''), ('', 'kim', ''), ('Jees', '', ''), ('', 'John', ''), ('', 'Mary', ''), ('', '', 'he')]
```

**OR**

Without any capturing groups,

```
>>> import re
>>> a=[]
>>> with open('qwert.txt', 'r') as f:
...     for line in f:
...         res = re.findall(r'(?<=Prof[.])\w+|(?<=As )\w+|\w+(?==\w)', line, re.M)
...         if res:
...             a.extend(res)
... 
>>> a
['every', 'Keel', 'goodthing', 'Tensa', 'kim', 'Jees', 'John', 'Mary', 'he']
```